# undefinded при работе с массивом

Tags: javascript, массивы

Когда беру что либо из массива и изменяю регистр то либо всё заменяется на undefinded, либо он добавляется из ниоткуда

```
arr = ['Hello', 'World'];
let x
what = arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    x += item.toLowerCase()[0] + ' '
  });
console.log(x)
```

ожидается, что выведет 'h w', а выводит 'undefinedh w'

Answer (score 1):

При объявлении переменной не присвоено значение

```
let x
```

По умолчанию присваивается `undefined`.

При сложении с первой буквой `undefined` приводится к строке.

Для решения достаточно инициализировать пустой строкой:

```
let x = '';
```

```js
arr = ['Hello', 'World'];
let x = '';
what = arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    x += item.toLowerCase()[0] + ' '
  });
console.log(x)
```